# Динамическое добавление полей со значением в форму

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii

Всем привет.
Есть функция:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#add').click(function(){
            var str = '<div>';
            str+= '<input type="text" value=""/> ';
            str+= '<input type="button" value="-" class="remove"/>';
            $('#sites').append(str);
        });
        $('.remove').live('click', function() {
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Она добавляет пустое поле в div ниже:

```
echo CHtml::openTag('div', ['id' => 'sites']);
echo CHtml::closeTag('div');
```

Как нужно изменить ее чтобы добавлялось поле такого формата:

```
echo $form->dropDownList($door,'type',$door->typeList(),
    ['name' => DoorSale::class.'[type]['.$door->id.']']);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант, попробовать в JS скрипте отправлять AJAX запрос. На сервере написать скрипт который принимает этот запрос, генерирует ваш "dropDownList",  и возвращает его код (html) в ответе, на этот AJAX запрос. Соответственно принять этот ответ (html код) в JS скрипте и встраивать его, куда вам нужно...